# escape characters (e.g. quotes) using JAXB Marshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I need use a XmlAdapter because I want do not have empty XLM object:

```
<TACHES>
    <TACHE>
        <NB_HEURE>7.75</NB_HEURE>
        <NOTES>foo</NOTES>
        <CODE_TACHE>1234</CODE_TACHE>
    </TACHE>
    <TACHE>                 <- I Want delete this part
        <NB_HEURE/>         <- I Want delete this part
        <NOTES/>            <- I Want delete this part 
        <CODE_TACHE/>       <- I Want delete this part 
    </TACHE>                <- I Want delete this part 
</TACHES>
```

My POJO is:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "TACHES")
public class Tasks {
    private List<Task> tasks;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TaskAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(name = "TACHE")
    public List<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }
    public void setTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }
}
```

My XmlAdapter is:

```
public class TaskAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Task> {
    @Override
    public Task unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String marshal(Task t) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Task.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
        m.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        if ("".equals(t.getNotes()) && "".equals(t.getHourCount()) && "".equals(t.getTaskCode())) {
            return null;
        }
        m.marshal(t, sw);
        String s = sw.toString();
        s = s.substring(s.indexOf("<TACHE>") + 7, s.indexOf("</TACHE>"));
        System.out.println(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

System.out.println of XmlAdapter print:

```
<NB_HEURE>7.75</NB_HEURE>
<NOTES>foo</NOTES>
<CODE_TACHE>1234</CODE_TACHE>
```

but, when I marshal global POJO, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
...
<TACHES>
    <TACHE>
        &lt;NB_HEURE&gt;7.75&lt;/NB_HEURE&gt;
        &lt;NOTES&gt;foo&lt;/NOTES&gt;
        &lt;CODE_TACHE&gt;1234&lt;/CODE_TACHE&gt;
    </TACHE>
</TACHES>
...
```

My is:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MoReports.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
m.marshal(moReports, sw);
xmlString = sw.toString();
```

Comment: I think that's beacuse JAXB treats the tags (inside TACHE) as values so they get escaped. While not an elegant solution, you can always modify the resulting XML replacing the escaped characters with < and > respectively.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

I do not use 'TaskAdapter extends XmlAdapter'

**Step 2**

I set `JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT` at `FALSE`

```
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);
```

**Step 3**

and I add this code post marshal

```
xmlString = removeAllEmptyXmlTags(xmlString);

public String removeAllEmptyXmlTags(String xml) {
    final String regex1 = "<([a-zA-Z0-9-\\_]*)[^>]*/>";
    final String regex2 = "<([a-zA-Z0-9-\\_]*)[^>]*>\\s*</\\1>";
    final Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex1);
    final Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile(regex2);

    String xmlString = xml;

    Matcher matcher1;
    Matcher matcher2;
    do {
        xmlString = xmlString.replaceAll(regex1, "").replaceAll(regex2, "");
        matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(xmlString);
        matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(xmlString);
    } while (matcher1.find() || matcher2.find());

    return xmlString;
}
```

**Step 4**

and I add this code post marshal

```
xmlString = xmlIndent(xmlString, false);

public String xmlIndent(String xml, Boolean ommitXmlDeclaration) {
    Writer outxml = new StringWriter();
    try {
        DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        OutputFormat format = new OutputFormat(doc);
        format.setIndenting(true);
        format.setIndent(2);
        format.setOmitXMLDeclaration(ommitXmlDeclaration);
        format.setLineWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        XMLSerializer serializer = new XMLSerializer(outxml, format);
        serializer.serialize(doc);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        return xml;
    }
    return outxml.toString();
}
```

**Result is OK:**

```
<TACHES>
    <TACHE>
        <NB_HEURE>7.75</NB_HEURE>
        <NOTES>foo</NOTES>
        <CODE_TACHE>1234</CODE_TACHE>
    </TACHE>
</TACHES>
```